# How do I create a wrapper for a pragma and have it compile properly?

Tags: c++, openmp, pragma

I've been trying to build a wrapper around MPI and OpenMP to have unified format to code in instead of having to keep switching between MPI_xxx, omp_xxx and #pragma omp xxx.

I've been having issues creating a wrapper around the various #pragma omp directives, so far the best I've gotten is to have it as:

```
#define _mmc_(x) _Pragma("omp ## #x")
```

(mmc is the tentative name for my library)

So if I wanted to have

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

The corresponding wrapper should be

```
_mmc_(parallel for)
```

However when it compiles the compiler seems to evaluate it differently, giving me the compilation warning

```
test.cpp:22:0: warning: ignoring #pragma omp  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
     _mmc_(parallel for)
```

I am compiling with mpic++ for MPICH 3.0.4 around gcc 4.8.4 in Ubuntu 14.04, with the flags

```
-fopenmp -lm -std=c++11 -Wall
```

Is there something that I can do or add to the code to make this work, or is this just something that cannot be done with the current tools?

Comment: Small note: global names beginning with underscores are reserved for the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, [as seen here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0747fee2a4c7edf9):

```
#define PRAGMA(x) _Pragma(#x)
#define _mmc_(x) PRAGMA(omp x)
```

`_Pragma` is a bit strict on taking a string literal, so we make that literal from the entire pragma argument string rather than piecing it together inside `_Pragma`. Preprocessor operators will not work inside a string literal, as you've tried in your post.

Comment: Thanks! This works exactly as I wanted. Also thanks for the note on names beginning with underscores, I had completely forgotten about that.